# Почему комментарии не отображаются на конкретной странице, а на всех?

Tags: php, mysqli

Комментарии на сайте отображаются благодаря следующему коду:

```
  <form class="form_comments" action="comments.php" method="post">
    <textarea class="com_text" name="text_comment" maxlength="222" placeholder="Оставьте Ваш комментарий"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?php echo $art['id']; ?>">
    <input class="sb" type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
```

Файл comments.php

```
<?php
  $page_id = $_POST["page_id"];
  $text_comment = $_POST["text_comment"];
  $text_comment = htmlspecialchars($text_comment);// Преобразуем спецсимволы в HTML-сущности
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123", "db");// Подключается к базе данных
  $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `comments` (`page_id`, `text_comment`) VALUES ('$page_id', '$text_comment')");// Добавляем комментарий в таблицу
  header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);// Делаем реридект обратно
?>
```

И вывод на страничке:

```
  <?php
  $result = $connection->query("SELECT id FROM `films`");
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  $page_id = $row['id']; // уникальный id фильма
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123", "db");// Подключается к базе данных
    $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `page_id`='$page_id'"); //Вытаскиваем все комментарии для данной страницы
    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
      print_r($row); //Вывод комментариев
      echo "<br>";
    }
  ?>
```

Есть таблица films в которой id имеет уникальный идентификатор фильма.
И comments в которой есть id,page_id (id страницы, на которой был оставлен комментарий), text_comment.

Проблема в том, что комментарии написанные допустим под фильмом с id 1 отображаются и под другими тоже.

---

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема?

Comment: Ну а вы понимаете __что__ возвращает запрос `SELECT id FROM \`films\``?

Comment: Возвращает id фильма?

Comment: А какого фильма?

Comment: Возвращает Id Текущего?

Comment: Скажите __где__ в запросе `SELECT id FROM \`films\`` есть указание на __текущий__ фильм?

Comment: Намёк понял. Т.е. надо ORDER BY `id` ?

Comment: Не поняли. Что даст вам `ORDER BY id`?

Comment: А что сделать нужно тогда?

Comment: Знать id текущего фильма. Где он у вас в скрипте есть?

Comment: Так "SELECT * FROM `films` WHERE `id` = " . (int) $_GET['id']) ?

Comment: Ну хотя бы так да.

Comment: Спасибо дружище!

Answer (score 0):

Для получения конкретного фильма вам необходимо например добавить GET параметр: film.php?id=1 - где 1 будет id фильма который вытаскивается в данный момент

Далее код вывода меняется:

```
<?php
    $page_id = $_GET['id']; // уникальный id фильма
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123", "db");// Подключается к базе данных
    $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `page_id`='$page_id'"); //Вытаскиваем все комментарии для данной страницы
    while ($row = $result_set->fetch_assoc()) {
      print_r($row); //Вывод комментариев
      echo "<br>";
    }
  ?>
```